# How to disable console-kit-daemon in Xubuntu 12.10?

Tags: xubuntu, services, console-kit

I just want to know how to disable `console-kit-daemon` in Xubuntu 12.10.

**Background**

In the last months I tried Ubuntu and I faced a memory error related to `console-kit-daemon` that spawned too much threads and was eating some 500mb of memory... I had switched to Xubuntu distro, to test if Desktop environment was the problem, but no. Lately, I got the same problem in Xubuntu 12.10. Now I want to try *disabling this service* to see if it can fix the memory related problem.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow these steps to disable it:

1. Kill the console-kit-daemon process if it's still running. You can use `pkill` or `kill` command and use: `$ps aux| grep console-kit-daemon` to get the id of the process.
2. Remove the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.service` (or move it to some place where you could restore it, if necessary). If can't find this file here please use `locate`/`find` command to find this file.
3. Reboot and you will see that console-kit-daemon no longer automatically starts up.

If it doesn't work please feel free to *ask* or you may want to try removing this service from /etc/init.d/ folder if available or use service command to stop this service.